# Codeigniter session automatically getting destroyed?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am working on CodeIgniter-2.2.2. I have following config settings in my config file.

My session is automatically getting destroyed after 2-3 minutes.
Any one help me for solution...

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

Comment: Can you add more details on what you observe?

Answer (score 0):

It is about underline.

Please change `$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';` line like this:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'cisession';
```

Probably it will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I see this :

```
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
```

Try to set to FALSE.

Here is mine :

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 14400;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 3600;
```

Hope it will work.